# Looking for concurrent map supporting events

Tags: java, concurrency, dictionary, event-handling

I'm looking for a concurrent map that supports event notification, e.g. I can register a callback for specific keys that are invoked on put or remove on such a key. And the whle thing is not only atomic, but also shows a good degree of concurrency as with ConcurrentHashMap.

My first attempt was to steal the segment-based solution from ConcurrentHashMap and add some event registry to the segment class. But this turned out to be harder than anticipated. Calculating the segment offset seems not that trivial. Just stealing the solution from ConcurrentHashMap is not that easy if you don't understand how it works (you miss some details and your stuff ends up being buggy). Maybe anybody knows of some paper that explains how the segment solution in ConcurrentHashMap works? Than I could work my way through.

It is easy to just put a big synchronized block in my map put or remove method so that the put or remove and invocation of the listeners all happens in one synchronized block. But this would degrade concurrency in the end to a solution being kind of a ConcurrentHashMap with a single segment.

I'm hoping for someone who knows of some map or event registry implementation that does what I want or some link to some paper explaining how this segmentation algorithm in COncurrentHashMap works.

Thanks, Oliver

Comment: Think I found something useful now: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/AversionofHashtablesupportingconcurrencyforbothretrievalsandupdates.htm The segment solution there is very simple and is probably sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: Would this be helpfull?
 http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingConcurrentMap.html

Comment: Thanks, from what I can see this map does not allow for callback listeners on put/remove to be added.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would be to intercept calls to a `ConcurrentHashMap` to get notified by events you register. One way to do so is to subclass ConcurrentHashMap, as in the following example:

```
class ConcurrentHashMapWithEvent<K, V> extends ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> {
  ...
  @Override public V put(K key, V value) {
    System.out.println("This is right before put(" + k + ", " + v + ")");
    super.put(k, v);
    System.out.println("This is right after put(" + k + ", " + v + ")");
  }
  ...
  public void registerCallback(EventCondition cond, Callback callback) { ... }
}
```

Instead of `println`, you would have some logic to check if `k`, `v`, the state of the map or whatever, matches some of the `EventCondition`, and launch the corresponding callbacks.

This sort of *pattern*, ie, intercepting method calls to execute some code before and some code after, is called [**Aspect Oriented Programming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: Yes, thanks. The problem is that iterating over the registered listeners after a put or remove has to happen without a context switch being able to come in between the put/remove and the invocation of the listeners. Otherwise you can run into a situation where the invocatin of the listeners is not in line in time with the put/remove operation, e.g. the order in which listeners are invoked does not reflect the order of put/remove operations. Therefore the put/remove and listener invocation has to be in one synchroniozed block degrading concurrency.